# What is 'atribution' key in tomTomMap.addSource()?

Tags: javascript, tiles, openweathermap

I was looking how to put openweathermap layer to tom-tom map, and I've found one solution:

```
tomTomMap.addSource('owm_source', {
    type: 'raster',
    tiles: [
      'https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/clouds_new/{1}/{51}/{20}.png?{app_id}'
    ],
    tileSize: 256,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 12,
    attribution: openWeatherMapAttribution
  });
```

I don't have idea what this 'atribution' is, and because of it I'm keep getting
Can you help me with finding out what is it, please?

```
Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading
    at r._checkLoaded (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at r.addSource (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at n.addSource (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at t.<computed> [as addSource] (mapFactory.js:1121)
    at script.js:59**
```

Answer (score 0):

An attribution is just a simple HTML snippet, with a link to the vendor. This is very badly documented by tomtom.

So the `openWeatherMapAttribution` variable could simply be the string: `'<a href="//example.org">Copyright</a>'`.

You can check their docs [here](https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-web-js/documentation#Maps.TomTomAttributionControl), however, as mention it's very badly documented.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a little retarded, but I don't have a clue what link should I put here when working with OpenWeatherMap, maybe you know?